# FileStream BeginRead system.IO.IOExceptional error: A device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# programming and I'm developing an application which uses TUN-TAP network adapter.

I am getting system.IO.IOException error: A device attached to the system is not functioning.

- Background:
  I have installed Openvpn TAP-windows adapter to my system. by running an simple application i want to get the data which is coming out of server which is running in the same machine and send it in other form.

To recieve the data from server to my application i coded simple as below.

```
    public static void TunInterfaceThread()
    {            
        const string UsermodeDeviceSpace = "\\\\.\\Global\\";

        // Getting the device GUId
        string devGuid = GetDeviceGuid();
        Console.WriteLine("Device GUID: " + devGuid);

        Console.WriteLine(HumanName(devGuid));

        // Create a win32file for manipulating the TUN/TAP interface 
        IntPtr ptr = CreateFile(UsermodeDeviceSpace + devGuid + ".tap", FileAccess.ReadWrite,
            FileShare.ReadWrite, 0, FileMode.Open, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, IntPtr.Zero);

        // Have Windows consider the interface now connected
        int ioctl_len;
        IntPtr pstatus = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(4);
        Marshal.WriteInt32(pstatus, 1);
        DeviceIoControl(ptr, TAP_CONTROL_CODE(6, METHOD_BUFFERED) /* TAP_IOCTL_SET_MEDIA_STATUS */, pstatus, 4,
                pstatus, 4, out ioctl_len, IntPtr.Zero);

        // Configure with the right IP address + mask and switch to TUN mode (by default the interface runs in TAP mode)
        IntPtr ptun = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(12);
        Marshal.WriteInt32(ptun, 0, 0x0101a8c0);  //192.168.1.1: IP address of the TUN interface
        Marshal.WriteInt32(ptun, 4, 0x0001a8c0);  //192.168.1.0: IP address of the TUN interface's network
        Marshal.WriteInt32(ptun, 8, unchecked((int)0x00ffffff)); // 255.255.255.0: netmask of the TUN interface
        DeviceIoControl(ptr, TAP_CONTROL_CODE(10, METHOD_BUFFERED) /* TAP_IOCTL_CONFIG_TUN */, ptun, 12,
            ptun, 12, out ioctl_len, IntPtr.Zero);

        SafeFileHandle handleValue = null;
        handleValue = new SafeFileHandle(ptr, true);
        Tap = new FileStream(handleValue, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FILE_STREAM_SIZE, true);

        // A buffer used for storing packets as they come in
        // Since this is single threaded, we are handling only one packet at a time 
        byte[] TUNBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

        // Creating a state variable for reading and writing 
        object read_state = new int();
        object write_state = new int();

        // Creating event wait handles, one for reading and the other for writing
        // and initializing them to be signaled automatically 
        ReadWaitObject = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
        WriteWaitObject = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

        // Creating two asynchronous callback functions 
        AsyncCallback readCallback = new AsyncCallback(ReadDataCallback);
        AsyncCallback writeCallback = new AsyncCallback(WriteDataCallback);
        IAsyncResult read_res, write_res;

        int number_of_tun_msgs = 0;
        int number_of_tcpRecv_msgs = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            {
                // Begin an asynchronous read. The callback function readCallback() will be called 
                try
                {                   
                    read_res = Tap.BeginRead(TUNBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE, readCallback, read_state);
                    // blocks the current thread until the read is complete and the event wait handle is signaled with ReadWaitObject.Set()
                    ReadWaitObject.WaitOne();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Tap read exception " + e.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
           Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

After recieving data i copy into a buffer and carry my other process.

This method works me for sometime, after certain period of time i recieve the IO exception error and i had to restart my application to work.

Please help me to understand what is the main reason behind IO exception error? is it my application having problem or the TAP-Adapter which is running in machine have some issue.

Comment: I am curious.. can you not get the same information if you were to do this using `WMI`

Comment: I am not sure about it.. using this program only i have a TCP connection i use networkstream to send the same data which is recieved by beginread